The transaction has been reverted to the initial state in remix
I have made a solidity contract to make challan system on ethereum blockchain but remix is giving errors, I am not able to deploy the contract.
Here first need to issue a challan, then we can make a payment from challan id
parse and convert function is to take string input for testing in remix and converting into int256
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ChallanManagement {
    address public owner;
    uint64 public userChallanCount;
    uint64 public vehicleChallanCount;

    struct Challan {
        uint256 challanId;
        uint256 vehicleId;
        uint256 amount;
        bool paid;
        string reason;
        uint256 issueDate;
        string location;
    }

    mapping(address => Challan[]) public Challans;
    mapping(uint256 => Challan) public allChallans;

    event ChallanIssued(
        address indexed user,
        uint256 challanId,
        uint256 vehicleId,
        uint256 amount,
        string reason,
        string location,
        uint256 issueDate
    );

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the contract owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function parseAndConvert(string memory input) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 result;
        assembly {
            result := mload(add(input, 32))
        }
        return result;
    }

    function issueChallan(
        string memory _vehicleId,
        string memory _amount,
        string memory _reason,
        string memory _location
    ) public {
        uint256 challanId = uint256(
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, block.timestamp))
        );

        uint256 __vehicleId = parseAndConvert(_vehicleId);
        uint256 __amount = parseAndConvert(_amount);

        uint256 issueDate = timeCall();

        Challan memory newChallan = Challan(
            challanId,
            __vehicleId,
            __amount,
            false,
            _reason,
            issueDate,
            _location
        );
        userChallanCount += 1;

        Challans[msg.sender].push(newChallan);
        allChallans[challanId]=newChallan;

        emit ChallanIssued(
            msg.sender,
            challanId,
            __vehicleId,
            __amount,
            _reason,
            _location,
            issueDate
        );
    }

    function timeCall() public view returns (uint256) {
        return block.number;
    }
    event ChallanPaid(address indexed payer, uint256 challanId, uint256 amount);

    function payChallan(uint256 _challanId, address payable _recipient) public payable {
        Challan storage challan = allChallans[_challanId];
        require(!challan.paid, "Challan already paid");
        require(msg.value >= challan.amount, "Insufficient funds to pay challan");

        challan.paid = true;

        (bool success,) = _recipient.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed");

        emit ChallanPaid(msg.sender, challan.challanId, challan.amount);
    }



    function getUserChallans(
        address _userAddress
    ) public view returns (Challan[] memory) {
        return Challans[_userAddress];
    }

    function getChallanDetails(
        uint256 _challanId
    ) public view returns (Challan memory) {
        // uint256 challanId = parseAndConvert(_challanId);
        return allChallans[_challanId];
    }
    
    function getUserChallanCount() public view returns (uint64) {
        return userChallanCount;
    }

    function getVehicleChallanCount(
        string memory _vehicleId
    ) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 vehicleId = parseAndConvert(_vehicleId);
        uint256 count = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < Challans[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            if (Challans[msg.sender][i].vehicleId == vehicleId) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    function getChallansForVehicle(
        string memory _vehicleId
    ) public view returns (Challan[] memory) {
        uint256 vehicleId = parseAndConvert(_vehicleId);
        Challan[] memory vehicleChallans = new Challan[](
            getVehicleChallanCount(_vehicleId)
        );
        uint256 index = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < Challans[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            if (Challans[msg.sender][i].vehicleId == vehicleId) {
                vehicleChallans[index] = Challans[msg.sender][i];
                index++;
            }
        }
        return vehicleChallans;
    }
}

payable function is not working even when passing value before deploy...
Getting error when deploying:
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
Rest of the functions are working fine
